# How to implement collapsing and expanding of a list using thymeleaf?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have a `HashMap` (called `test`) in the following format: `HashMap<String,List<MyClass>>`.

I would like to show the items of the `HashMap` value as expandable titles under which you can find the information of each object of the list.

I have the following code, but what I see in the expanded list is just one row per each title. Actually, the items of the list are overridden by the next one in the for loop.

```
<tbody>
  <tr th:each="element, iterStat  : ${test}">
    <td data-toggle="collapse" th:attr="data-target=|#demo${iterStat.count}|" th:text="${element.key}">keyvalue</td>

    <tr class="accordian-body collapse" th:id="'demo' + ${iterStat.count}" th:each="anews : ${element.value}">
      <td th:text="''">Place name</td>
      <td th:text="${anews.first_point}">First point</td>
      <td th:text="${anews.second_point}">Second point</td>
    </tr>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

How should I correct my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want it to do?

```
<tbody>
    <th:block th:each="element, iterStat  : ${test}">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" data-toggle="collapse" th:data-target="|.demo${iterStat.count}|" th:text="${element.key}" />
        </tr>

        <tr th:class="|accordian-body collapse demo${iterStat.count}|" th:each="anews : ${element.value}">
            <td th:text="''">Place name</td>
            <td th:text="${anews.first_point}" />
            <td th:text="${anews.second_point}" />
        </tr>
    </th:block>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. It shows all the rows, but the list is  already expanded and can't be collapsed.

Comment: How about now (had two class attribute sections).

Comment: No, unfortunately, not yet :(. It shows just the key values without possibility to click on them to show the nested list.

Comment: What shows in the "class" attribute for the child rows?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question? Sorry, I'm really new to thymeleaf and bootstrap and I have created this code just with copy and paste :). So, it would be great if you could explain  your goal more explicitly to me :). How can I evaluate the value of class for the rows?

Comment: view the source in the browser, and show what is in `<th class="???" ...>`

Comment: I see tr class="accordian-body collapse demo1" there. I have actually three items which are expandable, the first one has demo1, the second one (which includes a list of three items) has demo2 value for all the three items and the third one has demo3 as its value.

Answer (score 0):

I  just updated the verisons of bootstrap and jquery to the latest one and it worked. I used finally the following ones:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```